# Do Windows API EnumWindows and EnumChildWindows functions behave differently in Windows XP and 7

Tags: c#, windows, windows-7, .net-4.0, windows-xp

I am using 2 Windows API exported functions from c#.NET 4.0.

```
private const string WINDOW_EXCEL7 = "XLMAIN";
private const string CHILDWINDOW_XLMAIN = "EXCEL7";
```

I am searching for windows titles of Excel main windows' child windows (Excel has an MDI window of class XLMAIN containing 0, 1 or more child windows with EXCEL7 window class).

The goal is to find if a an excel workbook is being opened in any instances of Excel application. I did it by finding all XLMAIN IntPtr (pointers) and traversing children until I get a IntPtr with EXCEL7 window class at which point I can read child windows title and determine if a file is opened.

Basically this works on Windows XP, but not on Windows 7. I didn't try in Windows Vista.
What has changed? Can someone debug the issue since I don't have Windows 7.
Thanks
Rad

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace ExcelChildWindowsTitle
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //XLMAIN/EXCELDESK/EXCEL7 as seen by Spy++ VS 2010 utility
        //IntPtr hWnd = WndSearcher.SearchForWindow("XLMAIN", "EXCEL7", "icui-20110331.xls", ref workbookTitle);
        //bool excelProofFound = WindowTitleSearcher.SearchForWindow("XLMAIN", "EXCEL7", "testfileopenedinEXCEL.xls", ref workbookTitle);

        bool excelProofFound = WindowTitleSearcher.SearchForWindow("icui-20110331.xls");
        if (excelProofFound)
            Console.Write(":)))))))) Proof File opened in an Excel process;");
        else
        {
            Console.Write(":|Proof File not found");
        }
    }

public static class WindowTitleSearcher
{
    private const string WINDOW_EXCEL7 = "XLMAIN";
    private const string CHILDWINDOW_XLMAIN = "EXCEL7";

    public static bool SearchForWindow(string title)
    {
        SearchData sd = new SearchData { Wndclass = WINDOW_EXCEL7, ChildWndclass = CHILDWINDOW_XLMAIN, ChildTitle = title, WorkbookTitle = String.Empty};
        EnumWindows(new EnumWindowsProc(EnumProc), ref sd);
        return (int)sd.hWnd > 0;
    }

    private static bool EnumProc(IntPtr hWnd, ref SearchData data)
    {
        const bool directOnly = false;
        // Check classname and title 
        // This is different from FindWindow() in that the code below allows partial matches
        StringBuilder sb1 = new StringBuilder(1024);
        GetClassName(hWnd, sb1, sb1.Capacity);
        Debug.WriteLine(sb1.ToString());
        if (sb1.ToString().StartsWith(data.Wndclass))
        {
            RecursiveEnumChildWindows(hWnd, directOnly, ref data);
            if ((int)data.hWnd > 0)
            {
                // Found the wnd, halt enumeration
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    private static void RecursiveEnumChildWindows(IntPtr parentHwnd, bool directOnly, ref SearchData data)
    {
        EnumChildWindows(parentHwnd, delegate(IntPtr hwnd, ref SearchData data1)
        {
            bool add = true;
            if (directOnly)
            {
                add = GetParent(hwnd) == parentHwnd;
            }

            StringBuilder sb1 = new StringBuilder(1024);
            GetClassName(hwnd, sb1, sb1.Capacity);
            Debug.WriteLine("Child:" + sb1.ToString());

            if (add)
            {

                if (sb1.ToString().StartsWith(data1.ChildWndclass))
                {
                    sb1 = new StringBuilder(1024);
                    //Window Caption
                    GetWindowText(hwnd, sb1, sb1.Capacity);
                    if (sb1.ToString().Contains(data1.ChildTitle))
                    {
                        data1.hWnd = hwnd;
                        data1.WorkbookTitle = sb1.ToString();
                        return false; // Found the wnd, halt enumeration
                    }
                }
            }
            return true;
        }, ref data);
    }

    private struct SearchData
    {
        // You can put any vars in here...
        public string Wndclass;
        public string ChildWndclass;
        public string ChildTitle;
        public IntPtr hWnd;
        public string WorkbookTitle;
    }
    # region Windows API declarations
    private delegate bool EnumWindowsProc(IntPtr hWnd, ref SearchData data);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    private static extern bool EnumWindows(EnumWindowsProc lpEnumFunc, ref SearchData data);

    //private static extern bool EnumWindows(EnumWindowsProc lpEnumFunc, [MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.Struct)] ref SearchData data);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    static extern bool EnumChildWindows(IntPtr hwndParent, EnumWindowsProc lpEnumFunc, ref SearchData data);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern int GetWindowText(IntPtr hWnd, StringBuilder lpString, int nMaxCount);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", ExactSpelling = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    private static extern IntPtr GetParent(IntPtr hWnd);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public static extern int GetClassName(IntPtr hWnd, StringBuilder lpClassName, int nMaxCount);
    # endregion
}
}
```

Comment: What "doesn't work"? I don't have Excel, so I can't debug your code for you.

Comment: Try calling your doctor and saying "My arm doesn't work. What's wrong?" and see if you get an answer. You won't, I promise, without a lot more information being provided. Likewise, you dump a bunch of code and say "this doesn't work" and expect help here. You won't get it without details about what "doesn't work" means. Do you get an error message? Does Windows blue-screen? Does Excel pop up a dialog that says "Bzzzt! I'm not telling you! Nanner nanner nanner!"? Please remember that we can't see your screen, read your mind, or know anything you don't tell us about your problem. Thanks. :)

Comment: Are XP and 7 both 32-bit or 64-bit OS?

Comment: Probably this code breaks on other versions of Office....

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. excelProofFound is true for XP (32 bit) machine and false for Windows 7 (64 bit). The problem with Excel automation is that I can only get at one Excel instance and my file in question may be opened in another instance. I am preparing to debug the issue using remote debugging (since Windows 7 machine is a test/UAT machine)

Answer (score 3):

Why use hacks like this when MS Office has documented automation support?

You can use [.NET](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/302084), the older [COM/OLE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OLE_Automation) [automation](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/216686) [interfaces](http://support.microsoft.com/?scid=kb;en-us;222101) or the super old [DDE interface](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/279721).

Comment: The problem with Excel automation is that I can only get at one Excel instance and my file in question may be opened in another instance. Is there some class and method that can help me find all running instances of Excel 2003/2007 and all titles of their workbooks in normal, minimized and maximized views.

Comment: @Rad, I'm also looking for a way to find all running instances; were you ever able to resolve this issue?

Answer (score -1):

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Diagnostics;


namespace ExcelChildWindowsTitle
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //XLMAIN/EXCELDESK/EXCEL7 as seen by Spy++ VS 2010 utility
            //IntPtr hWnd = WndSearcher.SearchForWindow("XLMAIN", "EXCEL7", "icui-20110331.xls", ref workbookTitle);
            //bool excelProofFound = WindowTitleSearcher.SearchForWindow("XLMAIN", "EXCEL7", "testfileopenedinEXCEL.xls", ref workbookTitle);

            bool excelProofFound = WindowTitleSearcher.SearchForWindow("file name here");
            if (excelProofFound)
                Console.Write(":)))))))) Proof File opened in an Excel process;");
            else
            {
                Console.Write(":|Proof File not found");
            }
        }

        public static class WindowTitleSearcher
        {
            private const string WINDOW_EXCEL7 = "XLMAIN";
            private const string CHILDWINDOW_XLMAIN = "EXCEL7";

            public static bool SearchForWindow(string title)
            {
                SearchData sd = new SearchData { Wndclass = WINDOW_EXCEL7, ChildWndclass = CHILDWINDOW_XLMAIN, ChildTitle = title, WorkbookTitle = String.Empty };
                EnumWindows(new EnumWindowsProc(EnumProc), ref sd);
                return (int)sd.hWnd > 0;
            }

            private static bool EnumProc(IntPtr hWnd, ref SearchData data)
            {
                const bool directOnly = false;
                // Check classname and title 
                // This is different from FindWindow() in that the code below allows partial matches
                StringBuilder sb1 = new StringBuilder(1024);
                GetClassName(hWnd, sb1, sb1.Capacity);
                Debug.WriteLine(sb1.ToString());
                if (sb1.ToString().StartsWith(data.Wndclass))
                {
                    RecursiveEnumChildWindows(hWnd, directOnly, ref data);
                    if ((int)data.hWnd > 0)
                    {
                        // Found the wnd, halt enumeration
                        return false;
                    }
                }
                return true;
            }

            private static void RecursiveEnumChildWindows(IntPtr parentHwnd, bool directOnly, ref SearchData data)
            {
                EnumChildWindows(parentHwnd, delegate(IntPtr hwnd, ref SearchData data1)
                {
                    bool add = true;
                    if (directOnly)
                    {
                        add = GetParent(hwnd) == parentHwnd;
                    }

                    StringBuilder sb1 = new StringBuilder(1024);
                    GetClassName(hwnd, sb1, sb1.Capacity);
                    Debug.WriteLine("Child:" + sb1.ToString());

                    if (add)
                    {

                        if (sb1.ToString().StartsWith(data1.ChildWndclass))
                        {
                            sb1 = new StringBuilder(1024);
                            //Window Caption
                            GetWindowText(hwnd, sb1, sb1.Capacity);
                            if (sb1.ToString().Contains(data1.ChildTitle))
                            {
                                data1.hWnd = hwnd;
                                data1.WorkbookTitle = sb1.ToString();
                                return false; // Found the wnd, halt enumeration
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    return true;
                }, ref data);
            }

            private struct SearchData
            {
                // You can put any vars in here...
                public string Wndclass;
                public string ChildWndclass;
                public string ChildTitle;
                public IntPtr hWnd;
                public string WorkbookTitle;
            }
            # region Windows API declarations
            private delegate bool EnumWindowsProc(IntPtr hWnd, ref SearchData data);

            [DllImport("user32.dll")]
            [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
            private static extern bool EnumWindows(EnumWindowsProc lpEnumFunc, ref SearchData data);

            //private static extern bool EnumWindows(EnumWindowsProc lpEnumFunc, [MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.Struct)] ref SearchData data);

            [DllImport("user32.dll")]
            [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
            static extern bool EnumChildWindows(IntPtr hwndParent, EnumWindowsProc lpEnumFunc, ref SearchData data);

            [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
            public static extern int GetWindowText(IntPtr hWnd, StringBuilder lpString, int nMaxCount);

            [DllImport("user32.dll", ExactSpelling = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
            private static extern IntPtr GetParent(IntPtr hWnd);

            [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
            public static extern int GetClassName(IntPtr hWnd, StringBuilder lpClassName, int nMaxCount);
            # endregion
        }
    }
}

/////////////////////Work good on Windows 10 64 bit
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.